# React-ClickDrag Child Component Callbacks

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have react svg component that has 2 children that use [react-clickdrag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clickdrag)

I'm trying pass a callback function from the parent to child components to be called on drag. The callback function is called as expected on drag but the `this` variable returns the child component rather than the parent component in the callback function.

Have I structured something incorrectly? Or is react-clickdrag modifying the `this`variable somehow?

---

Parent Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Bar from './Bar.jsx';
import Node from './Node.jsx';

class TimeSpan extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xPos: this.props.xPos,
      yPos: this.props.yPos,
      length: this.props.length
    };
  }

  changeStartPos(diffPos) {
    console.log(this); //returns child component
    this.setState({xPos: this.state.xPos + diffPos, length: this.state.length + diffPos});
  }

  changeEndPos(diffPos) {
    console.log(this); //returns child component
    this.setState({length: this.state.length + diffPos});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <g>
        <Node changePos={this.changeStartPos} xPos={this.state.xPos} yPos={this.state.yPos} radius={10} />
        <Node changePos={this.changeEndPos} xPos={this.state.xPos + this.state.length} yPos={this.state.yPos} radius={10} />
      </g>
    );
  }

}

export default TimeSpan;
```

---

Child Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import clickDrag from 'react-clickdrag';

class NodeComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lastPositionX: 0,
        lastPositionY: 0,
        currentX: this.props.xPos,
        currentY: this.props.yPos
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.dataDrag.isMoving) {
        this.props.changePos(nextProps.dataDrag.moveDeltaX);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <circle cx={this.props.xPos} cy={this.props.yPos} r={this.props.radius} fill="black" />
    );
  }

}

var Node = clickDrag(NodeComponent, {touch: true});

export default Node;
```

---

index:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import TimeSpan from './TimeSpan.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <svg style={{postion:'fixed', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <TimeSpan xPos={300} yPos={300} length={300} />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, $('#app')[0]);
```

---

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ES6 syntax your functions will not be bound automatically like they are when you use `React.createClass` so you'll have to explicitly bind them.

The best place to do this is in the `constructor` so it only happens once.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeStartPos = this.changeStartPos.bind(this);
    ...
}
```